# Implementing multiple Jekyll paginators at different endpoints

Tags: jekyll

In dividing my blog in to multiple classifications of posts, I'm perplexed why I cannot implement multiple paginators from different endpoints.

All posts from my site are contained within the `/_posts` directory, and I'm able to paginate all posts from my site's main `/index.html` iterating as:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, if I create a new page to paginate a filtered subset of posts, such as photos, that same code is an empty collection.

From page `/photos/index.html`:

```
---
layout: default
paginate_path: "/photos/page:num"
---

{% for post in paginator.posts %}
{% endfor %}
```

It seems that `paginate_path` can only be specified per site in the `_config.yml`, and not from within a page's front matter.

However, I would still presume paginator would not be empty.

What am I missing regarding pathing, configuration, or convention?

Answer (score 0):

All your posts are supposed to be in the `_posts` folder.
Outside of this folder they are considered as `pages`, and then, will not present in the `site.category.anyCategory` collection.

Comment: They are - all posts are in the `_posts` folder.  I'm trying to iterate those posts on a page other than my site's index.html.  My index.html works fine; however, other pages cannot iterate my post collection.

Comment: Private; although, I think the complexity is multiple paginators are not possible out of the box.  As well, re-reading the documentation requires index.html, but I don't think I can specify a new `paginate_path` in my page's front matter.  So, no easy built-in way to paginate from multiple endpoints.